# Is there an interpretation of the Beta Distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are cases in probability where one distribution has an "interpretation" in terms of another distribution: X ~ Gamma(k,1/m) for positive integer k, can be interpreted as the distribution of waiting times for the occurrence of k events from a Poisson process with mean m.

Since a Beta distribution can be derived from a variable transformation of X/(X+Y) where X~Gamma($\alpha$,1) and Y=Gamma($\beta$,1), is there is an interpretation of the Beta distribution in terms of the Gamma distribution in a similar manner?

TIA,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have almost answered your own question:  for a Poisson process which stops after $\alpha+\beta$ events, the proportion of the total time up to event number $\alpha$ has a $B(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution.

A related statements can be made about order statistics:  the distribution of the $k$th smallest of a sample of size $n$ from a continuous uniform distribution has a beta distribution $B(k, n-k+1)$.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. If I could impose on you with one more question: is there a source of text that might show this? I've never seen a proof (or strong argument) to this fact.

Comment: My first paragraph is a natural interpretation of what you wrote.  My second is well known, for example at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Order_statistics)